# My Visual Studio 2010 cannot debug my app suddenly

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 cannot debug my app suddenly.

I am working on a Silverlight application.

As I write code, I run the debugger as a test.

Everything has been going well but now, suddenly, after I run a build, the options to run in debug mode have vanished?  Even the little green arrow is greyed out.

What has happened that will make the debugger become inaccessible?  What sorts of things will make this occur?

Comment: Have you restarted Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the xap file, then do a clean/rebuild on the solution ?

Comment: I have rebooted and restarted Visual Studio.  I am pulling up a backed-up copy of the code before I reinstll Visual Studio because a reinstll will take many hours.

Comment: If I create a new app from scratch , I am able to run it from  debug mode

Comment: Maybe just try and reset your Visual Studio Settings back to defaults... ?

Comment: Make sure you are in the `Debug` mode and not `Release`.

Comment: @Ruby: You can click `Run` in Release as well.

Comment: @SLaks: YES! But you `cannot debug` in `Release`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved the problem and I think this is interesting and I post the answer here for the next poor soul that has to experience this.

The problem is that sometimes as you move the mouse around (early in the morning or late at night or if you are distracted, etc.) you can click on something without knowing it if your finger just twitches.  Or maybe there is something else that happened, who knows.

The point is this.  If you have a Visual Studio Solution that has more than one project, sometimes the other project might be a dll or a project that does not produce an exe.  If, somehow, that other project gets to be the default project without you realizing it, then after you do a build, you will not be able to run the debugger.  So the solution is to reset the executable project to be the default one.

{maybe a boss or collegue who is interested in your little DLL, decided to have a look at it and thought it would be harmless to remote to your computer and for some reason thought it was necessary to set it as the default project}

Comment: +1 for providing an answer to your own issue instead of just leaving the question unanswered.

Comment: I was fighting this for almost 10 minutes rebuilding, removing obj folders, *.sou... Some other project was Default since i just checked from SVN...